# Google Sheets - Using Countif in an Array Formula - Return Text Value

Tags: google-sheets

[Picture of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4YQY.png)

Hi,

I am trying to use an Array Formula on a Google Form Responses sheet - so the formula needs to be able to populate down for the whole column.

I am trying to count the number of "Yes" per row (max 4) and then if there are 4 return "Yes" (or "No" if there are not). The basic formula would be (and it works):

**=if(countif(AA2:AD2, "Yes")=4, "Yes", "No")**

However this will not work as an array formula for obvious reasons.

So far I have got the below to work:

**=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(A:A) = 1, "Test One", if(len(A1:A), COUNTIF(if(AA1:AD= "Yes", row(AA1:AA)), row(AA1:AA)),)))**

However this returns a number and I still it to return the Yes/No if it is equal to 4 or not.

I have tried to put an if statement in various places to do this however I seem to break it every time.

Does any one please have any suggestions on how to make this work? I have attached a picture if this helps explain it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When working with array formulas and results row by row, you can consider using BYROW. Try with:

```
=BYROW(AA2:AD,LAMBDA(each.IF(countif(each, "Yes")=4, "Yes", "No")))
```

If you want not to have "No" when there are empty rows you can do:

```
=BYROW(AA2:AD,LAMBDA(each.IF(COUNTA(each)=0,"",IF(countif(each, "Yes")=4, "Yes", "No"))))
```

This checks if there is any value in those four columns

Or use:

```
=BYROW(AA2:INDEX(AD:AD,MAX(ROW(A:A),A:A<>"")),LAMBDA(each.IF(countif(each, "Yes")=4, "Yes", "No")))
```

This limits the BYROW until the last column with values. Change A:A if needed with any column you know that will always be completed by the Form

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW((AA2:AD="yes")*1, LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))))
```

to remove zeros:

```
=INDEX(BYROW((AA2:AD="yes")*1, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(x))))))
```

to return yes/no:

```
=INDEX(IF(Y2:Y="",,IF(Y2:Y=4, "yes", "no")))
```